# Suggestion for sudo over ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, sudo

I need two suggestions for making my script working from local server as well as ssh execution

**1. How to update the sudoers**

In server i have a path

> /var/log/data/status/

all files of parent and child_dir are owned by tomcat user and group.

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tomcat tomcat 0 Feb 17 02:23 20221119.status
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tomcat tomcat 0 Feb 17 02:23 20221116.status
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tomcat tomcat 0 Feb 17 02:23 20221112.status
```

I want user named new_user to able to rename the files under the /var/log/data/status/ as part of my script. I have tried to edit my sudoers file like below but it to run without password because tomcat is application user does not have password, Unsure how to make sudoers changes for it.

```
 new_user  ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/bash /path/my_script [a-z_]* 20[0-9]*
```

what i want to achieve is, to run without any password

```
sudo -u new_user /bin/bash /path/my_script
```

**2. Run the script over ssh**

My another requirement is to run the same script from other server over ssh, if possible, please help with the syntax

- On server A (Login as my user iamsage) -

i need to run something like this

```
ssh new_user@remote_host "sudo -u new_user /path/my_script arg1 arg2"
```

Comment: Why do you want to run `sudo su - new_user /bin/bash /path/my_script` instead of `sudo -u new_user /path/my_script arg1 arg2`? Please [edit] your question to add requested information.

Comment: yep, typo thanks, updated it.

Comment: Please clean up your question, it is a bit confusing. Your title mentions `sudo su`, your question body talks about `sudo -u -`, and I guess what you actually want is `sudo -u` (with no extra `-`). Also, please clarify what you need to run: who runs the script? How? What command? Can `new_user` ssh into the machine? Can't you just do `ssh new_user@ip /path/my_script arg1 arg2`?

Comment: `{{/var/log/data/status/<some_files}}` is possible as a path, but it's quite unusual, and a path like that is unlikely to help when you're struggling with something else.

Comment: What's the `-` in `sudo -u - new_user ...`? Did you run the command? *Copy&paste* the command you run on your system and the resulting output or error message. Your `ssh` command lacks the host name. It does not make sense to use `sudo -u new_user` when your process is already running as `new_user` by `ssh new_user@host ...` There might be more misunderstanding in the question. Please explain what users are involved. `sudo su - new_user ...` or `sudo -u new_user  ...` allow *some other user* to run a command *as new_user*. You might need `new_user` to run a command as user or group `tomcat`.

Comment: sorry, sudo -u new_user   is what i need, i have updated my ssh command

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity yes the path is correct.

Comment: @roaima actually added that for highlighting, updated it now.

Comment: @roaima - to avoid the confusion, i have updated the path. actually that is the path where files that to be renamed are present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sudoers` line isn't quite right. Try this instead

```
your_user ALL=(new_user) NOPASSWD: /path/my_script
```

Then ensure your script is executable and has `#!/bin/bash` as its first line.

The big issue with the remote invocation suggestion is you're trying to log in as the new user, so you wouldn't need to use `sudo`. Try either of these but don't mix them:

```
ssh remote_host sudo -u new_user /path/my_script arg1 arg2
ssh new_user@remote_host /path/my_script arg1 arg2
```

In both cases it's quite permissible to quote the entire command intended for remote execution but I've not done that here